# How to display data from resultSet in Angular application

Tags: java, angular, rest, service

in resultSet of my java service I have some rows. How to display these rows in my angular application automatically (without clicking on button and e.t.c)?

Comment: can you please share your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to your API endpoint (whether on ngOnInit or as a result of any other action), then save the data in a variable and in html you can loop through this variable and display results.

```
getData() {
   const endpoint = `YOUR_ENDPOINT`;
   return this._http
     .get(endpoint);
}


resultSet: any[];

getData.subscribe(resultSet => {
  this.resultSet = resultSet;
});
```

**getData()** being a function that is returning an observable of your API call and **this.resultSet** is a global variable which will contain your dataset.

```
<div *ngFor="let data of resultSet">
    {{data}}
</div>
```

Comment: was this helpful for you? please give a feedback or accept the answer if that was what you were looking for.